# Popular special characters in git branch names

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I'm writing an application where I limit allowed characters in git branch names. Currently the limit is [a-zA-Z0-9/_-]+. What other special characters may be requested by users? I know that / is popular that's why I've included it, is there other such character?

Comment: The characters you have seem sufficient. Your users will just have to learn to live with it.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim: yeah exactly, but doing a step towards users trying to guess their needs before first version of software will be released, when things get settled. Got very lucky with discovering "/" so users will be more near happy.

Comment: Or you could just use `git check-ref-format` and not impose arbitrary and unpredictable limits.  Whatever value your app offers, this diminishes that value.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know what is *allowed*, see [the `git check-ref-format` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-check-ref-format.html).  Note that this is for full references; branch names by definition have the required at-least-one-slash since they start with `refs/heads/`.

"What's popular" is kind of opinion-based (probably the reason I see one close vote on here).